# Not able to display firebase auth exception error as toast message in flutter

Tags: string, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, toast

I am making an app in flutter using firebase for login and signup functionaity. I want to display the exception caused while this firebase auth as flutter toast so that the user can understand what's going wrong.

But the error.message provided by firebase is nullable string and flutter toast message needs a string as parameter so it' showing this error

> The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Code and error:

[image: code and error]

Can anyone help me out to display this?

```
 try{
   // code here
 }
 on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.message, gravity: ToastGravity.TOP);
      }
```

Comment: Try `msg: error.message ?? "Something went wrong"` or `msg: error!.message!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `!` (bang) operator:

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error!.message!, gravity: ToastGravity.TOP);
```

You can read more about [argument_type_not_assignable](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#argument_.type_not_assignable)

Answer (score -1):

use error.toString() to convert the error into String format